# How to short the expression?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have that expression

```
if (a === Infinity && b === 0 || a === -Infinity && b === 0 || a === 0 && b === Infinity || a === 0 && b === -Infinity) {
        return NaN
    }
```

I want short it, but I have no idea how to do this

**UPDATE**

If it possible, I cant use `isFinite()`, how to shorten else?

Comment: Can you add which type(s) `a` or `b` can have? Can they be strings, objects, booleans, ...etc? Or only number type?

Comment: only number type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `a` and `b` are number typed, then:

```
if (!(a*b || isFinite(a+b))) return NaN;
```

If your linter warns about use of global functions, then:

```
if (!(a*b || Number.isFinite(a+b))) return NaN;
```

If you can't use multiplication:

```
if (!(a && b || Number.isFinite(a+b))) return NaN;
```

Comment: but if I can't use isFinite(). What's then?

Comment: Can you explain why you can't us `isFinite`? Is this related to an older ECMAScript version? Which? Anyway, added alternative without `isFinite`.

Comment: I need to write code, which be agreed with eslint. Now, I get this eslint error: Unexpected use of 'isFinite'.eslintno-restricted-globals. Formally, I can use it, but I am in interesting, can I short this expression without isFinite()

Comment: You can also use `Number.isFinite`... will the linter accept that? (Updated answer)

Comment: Im sorry, but I forget to say that I can't use operator * in my exercise. I need to write function, which be multiply two values as: multiply(10, -2); //  -20
multiply(0, Infinity) // NaN

Comment: You can use `&&` logical operator instead of `*`. Added to answer.

Comment: Check the update. If you have a particular question about the code you just shared (implementing `multiple`), I suggest you ask a new question about that.

Comment: I post new question about it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69390648/how-to-get-rid-of-the-complexity-in-the-algorithm 
Check it, please

Comment: About use && instead * In my case it does not work

Answer (score 4):

You can use `!isFinite()` to test if it's either `Infinity` or `-Infinity`.

```
if ((!isFinite(a) && b === 0) || (!isFinite(b) && a === 0)) {
    return NaN;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but if I can't use isFinite(), how I can short it use only logical operators and brackets. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

`Math.abs`ing both and then checking that the minimum is 0 and the maximum is infinity should do it.

```
const nums = [a, b].map(Math.abs);
if (Math.min(...nums) === 0 && Math.max(...nums) === Infinity) {
  return NaN;
}
```

Can also sort the array.

```
const nums = [a, b]
  .map(Math.abs)
  .sort(a, b) => a - b); // .sort() works too, but could be more confusing
if (nums[0] === 0 && nums[1] === Infinity)) {
  return NaN;
}
```